# Smart groups and date checks

Tags: contacts, civireport, smartgroups, search-builder

I am trying to create a smart group that always returns the list of contacts whose membership end date is the end of the previous year or earlier (these are lapsed members and we need to chase them for renewal). I did find that I can do this using the advanced search, but that unfortunately the date ("31st December 2015" in this case) gets hard-wired in the query.

Then I thought maybe the search builder would help, but there the date searches do ***not work at all***. A drop-down calendar is presented, but the string used in the query seems to have a different date format ("20151231") from the field contents ("2015-12-31"). Is this a known bug?

In any case, there seems to be no way to let the date range "float" from year to year, so this means that this year's "membership has expired" query, will be wrong in a year's time.

I am using the current version of CiviCRM, V4.6.8, under the latest Wordpress version

Comment: I have now activated the membership update cron job which was not running and this helps by automatically setting the lapsed state. Nevertheless it would be just great if the search facilities would work correctly with dates!